# Saving last value of awk as variable

Tags: awk

I am using awk to parse a file and create new files (1...N) in the following way.

```
awk -F ';' '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i>NR}' file
```

This does what I need to do, but how do I save the last value of the for loop as a variable, consistent with the above? So for example, if i loops to 6, I want to set variable=6.

Comment: What do you need this variable for Do you want to maintain file numbering? Use awk 'your script' file1 file2 file3 ...

Comment: The last value of the loop is `NF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to save last value of for loop which I believe is number of fields if yes then please try following.

```
var=$(awk -F ';' '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i>NR;value=NF} END{print value}' file)
```

---

---

In case you want to save value for last line number(total lines in Input_file) then try following.

```
var=$(awk -F ';' '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i>NR;value=count++} END{print count}' Input_file)
```

OR in case your `awk` supports `FNR` in `END` block then simply do:

```
var=$(awk -F ';' '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i>NR} END{print FNR}' Input_file)
```

Note: OP haven't mentioned about it but thought to put it here, in case there are too many files getting created then it will be wise to use `close` command in awk to close them in background too by using `close(NR)` just an example here.

Comment: second script one is just `NR`

Comment: @karakfa, I know sir :) but why I used variable because in some awks don't remember versions it didn't work in END block for me;when I tried to use hence I stopped trusting it, anyways I will add it now sir, cheers.

Comment: Upvoted, Ravinder, that's a fine solution! But @karakfa is right, because both `NR` and `FNR` should be correctly defined in the END block according to [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03). That means any awk that fails to do that is actually broken! Cheers :)